# Add edit text row dynamically to table layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-tablelayout

```
________________________________________________________-
|__Name__________|___Number________|____Price___________|+|
________________________________________________________-
|__Name__________|___Number________|____Price___________|+|
________________________________________________________-
|__Name__________|___Number________|____Price___________|+|
```

CONFIRM

Hi, I need help with generating a code that performs the above. The user needs to input name, quantity and the price of goods purchased. The number of goods he can purchase is not limited and hence will be decided dynamically.

When the user clicks the 'plus' button, another row should appear below. When he clicks on confirm, the information from the edit texts should be stored and uploaded. Now I tried using a table layout and adding view dynamically but I don't know how to reference these dynamically created edit texts and get their inputted values.

Could someone please guide me.

Comment: I'd go for inserting the values in a database table and reload my ListView adapter.

Comment: Im aware of adding rows in a recycler view and achieving something similar to what I need. But I was wondering if there was any other more efficient way of doing the same.

Comment: In my opinion `RecyclerView` or `ListView` would be much better to do this.

Comment: Keeping the things easy is often the best and more efficient way.

Comment: Ok sounds good but the issue is I need to extract the edit text value from the recycler view when a button outside the view is clicked.

Comment: I am having the same issue. did you get some solution for this ? @VarunAgarwal please help me with this

Comment: @SundarNivash Ya I was able to get a solution. Sadly its in another computer and not on github. Basically what I did was write a recycler view and added a dynamic view injector in the same class. The trick is that `recyclerview` CANNOT be in a different file, and must in the same file as the `activity` itself. Let me see if I can find that code, and i will post it.

Comment: thanks a lot. Please post that code. @VarunAgarwal